# How to create a temporary table in SSIS control flow task and then use it in VAL flow task?

Tags: ssis

I have a control flow where I create a temp database and table in a with a T-SQL Command. When I add a dataflow I would like to query the table but I can't because the table doesn't exist to grab information from. When I try I get errors about logging in because the database doesn't exist (yet). I have delay validation to true.

If I create the database and table manually then add the dataflow with query and drop the database it sticks but it doesn't seem like a clean solution.

If there is a better way to create a temporary staging database and query it in dataflows please let me know.

Comment: You could try to use a script task to generate the source...

Comment: Are you creating a temporary table or a temporary database?

Comment: Could you use an object-type variable instead of a temp table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:
Set the property RetainSameConnection on the Connection Manager to True so that temporary table created in one Control Flow task can be retained in another task.
Here is a sample SSIS package written in SSIS 2008 R2 that illustrates using temporary tables.
Walkthrough:
Create a stored procedure that will create a temporary table named ##tmpStateProvince and populate with few records. The sample SSIS package will first call the stored procedure and then will fetch the temporary table data to populate the records into another database table. The sample package will use the database named Sora Use the below create stored procedure script.

```
USE Sora;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.PopulateTempTable
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..##tmpStateProvince') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE ##tmpStateProvince;

    CREATE TABLE ##tmpStateProvince
    (
            CountryCode     nvarchar(3)         NOT NULL
        ,   StateCode       nvarchar(3)         NOT NULL
        ,   Name            nvarchar(30)        NOT NULL
    );

    INSERT INTO ##tmpStateProvince 
        (CountryCode, StateCode, Name)
    VALUES
        ('CA', 'AB', 'Alberta'),
        ('US', 'CA', 'California'),
        ('DE', 'HH', 'Hamburg'),
        ('FR', '86', 'Vienne'),
        ('AU', 'SA', 'South Australia'),
        ('VI', 'VI', 'Virgin Islands');
END
GO
Create a table named dbo.StateProvince that will be used as the destination table to populate the records from temporary table. Use the below create table script to create the destination table.
USE Sora;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.StateProvince
(
        StateProvinceID int IDENTITY(1,1)   NOT NULL
    ,   CountryCode     nvarchar(3)         NOT NULL
    ,   StateCode       nvarchar(3)         NOT NULL
    ,   Name            nvarchar(30)        NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT [PK_StateProvinceID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
        ([StateProvinceID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY];
GO
```

Create an SSIS package using Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS). Right-click on the Connection Managers tab at the bottom of the package and click New OLE DB Connection... to create a new connection to access SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

Click New... on Configure OLE DB Connection Manager.

Perform the following actions on the Connection Manager dialog.

- Select Native OLE DB\SQL Server Native Client 10.0 from Provider
  since the package will connect to SQL Server 2008 R2 database
- Enter the Server name, like MACHINENAME\INSTANCE

  - Select Use Windows Authentication from Log on to the server section or whichever you prefer.
  - Select the database from Select or enter a database name, the
    sample uses the database name Sora.
  - Click Test Connection
  - Click OK on the Test connection succeeded message.
  - Click OK on Connection Manager

The newly created data connection will appear on Configure OLE DB Connection Manager. Click OK.

OLE DB connection manager KIWI\SQLSERVER2008R2.Sora will appear under the Connection Manager tab at the bottom of the package. Right-click the connection manager and click Properties

Set the property RetainSameConnection on the connection KIWI\SQLSERVER2008R2.Sora to the value True.

Right-click anywhere inside the package and then click Variables to view the variables pane. Create the following variables.
A new variable named PopulateTempTable of data type String in the package scope SO_5631010 and set the variable with the value EXEC dbo.PopulateTempTable. 
A new variable named FetchTempData of data type String in the package scope SO_5631010 and set the variable with the value SELECT CountryCode, StateCode, Name FROM ##tmpStateProvince

Drag and drop an Execute SQL Task on to the Control Flow tab. Double-click the Execute SQL Task to view the Execute SQL Task Editor.
On the General page of the Execute SQL Task Editor, perform the following actions.
Set the Name to Create and populate temp table
Set the Connection Type to OLE DB
Set the Connection to KIWI\SQLSERVER2008R2.Sora
Select Variable from SQLSourceType
Select User::PopulateTempTable from SourceVariable
Click OK

Drag and drop a Data Flow Task onto the Control Flow tab. Rename the Data Flow Task as Transfer temp data to database table. Connect the green arrow from the Execute SQL Task to the Data Flow Task.

Double-click the Data Flow Task to switch to Data Flow tab. Drag and drop an OLE DB Source onto the Data Flow tab. Double-click OLE DB Source to view the OLE DB Source Editor.
On the Connection Manager page of the OLE DB Source Editor, perform the following actions.
Select KIWI\SQLSERVER2008R2.Sora from OLE DB Connection Manager
Select SQL command from variable from Data access mode
Select User::FetchTempData from Variable name
Click Columns page

Clicking Columns page on OLE DB Source Editor will display the following error because the table ##tmpStateProvince specified in the source command variable does not exist and SSIS is unable to read the column definition.

To fix the error, execute the statement EXEC dbo.PopulateTempTable using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) on the database Sora so that the stored procedure will create the temporary table. After executing the stored procedure, click Columns page on OLE DB Source Editor, you will see the column information. Click OK.

Drag and drop OLE DB Destination onto the Data Flow tab. Connect the green arrow from OLE DB Source to OLE DB Destination. Double-click OLE DB Destination to open OLE DB Destination Editor.
On the Connection Manager page of the OLE DB Destination Editor, perform the following actions.
Select KIWI\SQLSERVER2008R2.Sora from OLE DB Connection Manager
Select Table or view - fast load from Data access mode
Select [dbo].[StateProvince] from Name of the table or the view
Click Mappings page

Click Mappings page on the OLE DB Destination Editor would automatically map the columns if the input and output column names are same. Click OK. Column StateProvinceID does not have a matching input column and it is defined as an IDENTITY column in database. Hence, no mapping is required.

Data Flow tab should look something like this after configuring all the components.

Click the OLE DB Source on Data Flow tab and press F4 to view Properties. Set the property ValidateExternalMetadata to False so that SSIS would not try to check for the existence of the temporary table during validation phase of the package execution.

Execute the query select * from dbo.StateProvince in the SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to find the number of rows in the table. It should be empty before executing the package.

Execute the package. Control Flow shows successful execution.

In Data Flow tab, you will notice that the package successfully processed 6 rows. The stored procedure created early in this posted inserted 6 rows into the temporary table.

Execute the query select * from dbo.StateProvince in the SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to find the 6 rows successfully inserted into the table. The data should match with rows founds in the stored procedure.

The above example illustrated how to create and use temporary table within a package

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely MUST have a database which only exists during the fleeting moments that your package is executing then do this...  Your first Control Flow item is an Execute SQL statement that creates the database.  Followed by another Execute SQL statement that creates the table.  Next, do your dataflow into the table and your queries.  Finally, as the last Control Flow item an Execute SQL statement with a DROP database command.  Done, temporary database.

The caveat to this - as you've noticed - is that in order to design the dataflow, the database must exist first. There is NO way around this.  The objects we are designing the dataflow against MUST exist in order to design it.  However, this problem only exists during the design phase. It's temporary.  Once the dataflow design is done, you can save the package and drop the database.  It'll stay gone until you run the package again.  Setting "delay validation" ensures that your dataflow won't attempt to validate existence of the database at the top of the package.  It will wait juuust before it is needed, after your CREATE database statement.  So you're good there.

However, before you implement this design, I have to ask. Why are we using a database like we would a variable?  Why CREATE it only to DROP it moments later?  I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that we are doing this because you wish to have the data in SQL where you can leverage the SQL language to selectively query and/or manipulate it?  If thats the case, the point of SSIS is to do this type of manipulation or querying using the provided dataflow transformation tools.  Also,  you didn't mention it in your question, but what is the final destination of your data?  We aren't just loading it to a database to have it dropped. So where does it end up? A flatfile?